Why is this sequence of functions pointwise convergent to $0$
Consider the following sequence of functions $f_n(x):[0,1] \mapsto \mathbb{R}$
$$f_n(x)= \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
n^2 x(1-n x), & x \in\left[0, \frac{1}{n}\right] \\
0, & x \in\left(\frac{1}{n}, 1\right]\\ 
\end{array}\right.$$
The maximum value of the sequence of functions is $\frac{n}{4}$ at $x=\frac{1}{2n}$.
Obviously, as $n$ increases, the maximum value of the sequence of functions increases.
Based on this, it violates the definition of pointwise convergence which says $\forall x \in D: \forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}: \exists N \in \mathbb{R}: \forall n>N:\left|f_n(x)-f(x)\right|<\epsilon$.
(https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Pointwise_Convergence)
So this sequence of functions does not pointwise converge to $f(x)=0$.
This is because we cannot find such $\epsilon$ since the maximum value grows as $n$ grows.
This question is from the following video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kq_KZpljeXo&t=1s (from 3:23). In this video, it says the sequence is pointwise convergent to $f=0$. I am quite confused about this.

For pointwise convergence, $N$ is allowed to depend on $x$; so once you have an $x$ in mind, you can pick an $N$ large enough to keep you in the zero part of your function.

The sequence satisfies the condition that you have written; in point of fact, we can even exhibit a function $u:D\times (0,\infty)\to \Bbb N$ such that $$\forall x\in D:\forall \epsilon>0:\forall n>u(x,\epsilon): \left\lvert f_{u(x,\epsilon)}-0\right\rvert<\epsilon$$ One such function is $u(x,\epsilon)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x=0\ \min{n\in\Bbb N,:, 1/n<x}&\text{if }x>0\end{cases}$.

@SassatelliGiulio But how to explain the maximum $n/4$ increases as $n$; then we cannot find such $\epsilon$ "for ALL $x$"?  This is the point I cannot figure out.

If you want one $N$ that works for all $x$, then you want uniform convergence, not pointwise -- pointwise convergence you treat every $x$ separately.

I think the confusion is because, with pointwise convergence, you can think of it as first fixing $x$ and then letting $n\rightarrow \infty$. This is because in the definition the $x$ is first and so $N$ can be a function of $x$, but not the other way around. Below is a more precise explanation.
To show pointwise convergence of $\{f_n\}$ to the zero function, consider any $x \in  (0,1]$. (Note $f_n(0) = 0$, and so we needn't consider that case.) Now let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. By the given definition, it suffices to show there is $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$ |f_n(x) - 0| <\varepsilon,\quad \mbox{for all}\ n>N.$$
By the Archimedean property of $\mathbb{R}$, there is a natural number $N$ such that $N > 1/x.$ This implies
$$x > \frac{1}{N}>\frac{1}{n},\quad \mbox{for all}\ n > N,$$
and, thus,
$$ |f_n(x) - 0| = | 0 - 0| = 0 < \varepsilon, \quad\mbox{for all} \ n>N,$$
as desired. Hence $f_n\rightarrow 0$ pointwise.

The problem is that you are choosing a value of $x$ which varies with $n$ as a counterexample, which is not included in the definition of pointwise convergence. Looking at the definition of pointwise convergence
\begin{align}
\forall x \in D: \forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}: \exists N \in \mathbb{R}: \forall n>N:\left|f_n(x)-f(x)\right|<\epsilon,
\end{align}
this says "I give you an $x$ and and $\epsilon$, can you give me an $N$ such that $\left|f_n(x)-f(x)\right|<\epsilon$ for all $n > N$?". If you can always find such an $N$ (which in general will depend on $x$ and $\epsilon$), no matter the values of $x$ and $\epsilon$ I give to you, then the function is pointwise convergent.
